# Can't use XMLGregorianCalendar in Android, even if it is documented?

Tags: android, datetime, w3c, xml-deserialization

I really can't understand this one: it looks like Android has the XMLGregorianCalendar class, because it is documented [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/xml/datatype/XMLGregorianCalendar.html).
But if you go ahead and try to use it, that's what you get:

```
10-27 17:21:43.677: E/AndroidRuntime(14850): Caused by: javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeConfigurationException: Provider org.apache.xerces.jaxp.datatype.DatatypeFactoryImpl not found
10-27 17:21:43.677: E/AndroidRuntime(14850):    at javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory.newInstance(DatatypeFactory.java:102)
```

This happens on the line:

```
DatatypeFactory datatype = DatatypeFactory.newInstance();
```

And guess what, it should not behave like this, as documented on the official [Android Javadoc](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/xml/datatype/DatatypeFactory.html#newInstance%28%29).

This looks like one of the not-so-smart things about Android. Why would you document something that can't be used?
Does anyone have a solution on this, one that maybe does not include repackaging?

Comment: On which Android version does this crash?

Comment: Android 2.3.3 Gingerbread on a Nexus One.

Comment: Well there goes that idea. I'll keep looking.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like even though it's been in the API since v8, [no version of Android has ever shipped with an implementation](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=14379). Handy, right?

One solution is to download the [Xerces2 Java implementation](http://xerces.apache.org/mirrors.cgi#binary) jar and include it on your project's build path.

Your code would be only slightly different:

```
DatatypeFactory datatype = DatatypeFactoryImpl.newInstance();
```

Comment: I've included xercesImpl.jar in my build path and copied to the lib directory but I am still getting error `Caused by: javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeConfigurationException: Provider org.apache.xerces.jaxp.datatype.DatatypeFactoryImpl not found`. Is there anything else I should do to get it working?

Comment: You can try this link. It contains the datatype jar especially for android http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.odftoolkit/odfdom-java/0.8.7/org/apache/xerces/jaxp/datatype/DatatypeFactoryImpl.java

Comment: @MartinNuc did you able to solve above problem you have mentioned above? I am facing the same problem can you please suggest me any solution.

Comment: @Neha sorry, I dont remember :(

Comment: @Neha @Martin You need to make sure you're using `DatatypeFactoryImpl.newInstance()` and not `DataTypeFactory.newInstance()` after including the .jar in your project.