# XMLGregorianCalendar instance in android

Tags: java, android, gregorian-calendar

I am trying to create an instance of `XMLGregorianCalendar` in android code

```
XMLGregorianCalendar startDate = javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar();
```

I am running into this error:

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.apache.xerces.jaxp.datatype.DatatypeFactoryImpl" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.comp.appname-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]

I have tried adding xerces for android jar 
but it is returning

```
mf.javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar
```

where as I have to create of type `javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar`.
Can someone please guide me how to create `XMLGregorianCalendar` instance?

Comment: did you have `org.apache.xerces` in your classpath?

Comment: I mean, in build.gradle? Why dont you use normal `Date` object or Joda-Time?

Comment: i am an external api in my code and that expects XMLGregorianCalendar for a date, so cant use other date types.
If i download and include xercesImpl, running in to the following exception :: 
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bad utf-8 byte a0 at offset 00000004

Comment: i have a eclipse based android project, let me know if you want me to check any thing. Also note that the exception is coming when i am running my android app

Comment: are you using gradle or maven?

Comment: it is a android proj created using eclipse. It is neither Maven nor gradle. i believe it internally uses ant (not sure though, my guess)

Comment: So, the second error is not related anymore, seems to be some issue with utf8

Comment: yep. as i mentioned above if i copy xerces jar to my libs folder, try to build project, it throws that utf-8 and does not build apk any more .. some more console log info
[2015-12-19 22:29:25 - CX3] Dx 1 error; aborting
[2015-12-19 22:29:25 - CX3] Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1

Comment: Probably This jar could be executed in Android environment

Comment: followed similar threads, but was of no help.. i am open to try different things ...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7918466/cant-use-xmlgregoriancalendar-in-android-even-if-it-is-documented

Comment: @venkata did u able to fix this problem.? I am facing the same issue...can you suggest me anything?

Comment: has anyone found a solution to this ???