# How to resolve "Provider org.apache.xerces.jaxp.datatype.DatatypeFactoryImpl not found" error in Android?

Tags: java, android, xml, calendar

Hi I am trying to use "XMLGregorianClander" in Android project. here is my simple code :

```
try
            {
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                String date = sdf.format(new Date());
                XMLGregorianCalendar xmlCal = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(date);

                String mm = String.valueOf( xmlCal.getMonth() );
                String dd = String.valueOf( xmlCal.getDay() );
                String yyyy = String.valueOf( xmlCal.getYear() );

                System.out.println( mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy );

            } catch ( Exception e ) {
                throw new RuntimeException( e );
            }
```

While running this code on Android using Eclipse I am getting folloing error :

```
javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeConfigurationException: Provider org.apache.xerces.jaxp.datatype.DatatypeFactoryImpl not found.
```

I have tried adding external jar `xerces-impl-2.9.0-sources.jar`but no luck.

Can any one please suggest me some solution how can i run above code on Android.

Thanks

Comment: is it necessary to use xmlgregorian? @Neha

Comment: yes @PratikDasa. my webservice wants date in that format only :(

Comment: @PratikDasa Also the thing is that when I run same code on java it works perfectly fine but when i try to run it android platform it throws above error.

Comment: as per me you can make any format using any other way also, tell me which format you needs? @Neha

Comment: or use this if its necessary http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7918466/cant-use-xmlgregoriancalendar-in-android-even-if-it-is-documented

Comment: @PratikDasa I already tried above solution its not working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124980/discussion-between-pratik-dasa-and-neha).

Comment: I suggest you to not use it...I think another solution work for this @Neha

Comment: anyone found an answer to this ...

Comment: Same problem here.

Comment: what was the solution